# Thread.sleep in a while loop? Host in IIS instead?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service

I am building a WPF frontend that interacts with another EXE that is acting as a TCP service. I had never looked at this before today... being focused on the front end..

However, when I looked at it today, it uses a While true loop with a Thread.sleep(5000) in it to keep it  alive and able to process requests from the GUI. However, this seems ridiculous. while it's sleeping, it can't respond to requests and this is causing the GUI to hang while it waits.

Shouldn't this be implimented as a service running in IIS or as a window's service? At least that way it would be more responsive and manageable through the IIS management console?

Thanks
Harold

Comment: It is often good idea to use existing tools (like IIS + ASP.Net WebAPI to host services), but you need to make decision yourself based on your goals/experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than sleeping in the loop, it should be waiting for new incoming requests.  IIS/ASP.NET could do this for you, but that may be overkill, and may impose hosting requirements that conflict with other requirements.  Assuming you don't want to use ASP.NET, a service in C# should inherit from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`, which has virtual functions you implement that are called to start and stop the service.  These should start and stop one or more secondary threads which do all the processing.  Depending on what kind of connection it is expecting, you'd have different ways of waiting for new requests.  Assuming it's raw sockets, Such processing should not involve sleeping, as it should be accepting connections on a socket with `Socket.Accept` and then waiting for instructions (request details) using `Socket.Receive`, then immediately processing the request and going back to waiting on new input.  None of those involve sleeping and make it possible to not only respond quickly, but respond to multiple requests simultaneously.